# Ag-Grid enable checkbox selection for a single rowNode

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

By getting a rowNode by its ID, is there any way I can enable/disable the select checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, but you can provide a callback function to the grid that takes a RowNode and returns a boolean.

Provide the function to the grid as the value of the GridOption's 'isRowSelectable' property.